# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

Tags: php, laravel

After updating laravel from 5.3 to 5.4 I'm getting error

```
In SocialAutoPostServiceProvider.php line 29:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()
```

Here code in  SocialAutoPostServiceProvider

```
$this->app['socialAutoPost'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
{
    return new SocialAutoPost();
});
```

Im using edujugon/social-auto-post packagist . 
I read that share function removed from laravel 5.4 . So What can I do? I cant remove this package .

SOLUTION:
I updated method to

```
$this->app['socialAutoPost'] = $this->app->singleton('socialAutoPost',function($app)
        {
            return new SocialAutoPost();
        });
```

And it works.